# Weird dependencies between array and a variable that is assigned by an element from that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, dependencies, k-means

When changing a variable that is assigned from an element of an array, that specific element in the array changes with the variable. However no where in the code is the array meant to change.

In the code the array is an array of objects, the variable is declared and assigned within the function randomCentroid (centroid), that function is called in initializeCentroid.

The code is used for generating random centroid regarding k-means clustering, Hereby the code:

```
//Return random centroid points with coloring
let randomCentroid = (fill) => {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length);
  let centroid = points[r];

  //points.splice(r, 1);
  centroid.fill = fill;
  return centroid;
}

//Gives distinct coloring to all centroid points
let initializeCentroids = (num) => {
  let allCentroids = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let color = colors(i);
    let centroid = randomCentroid(color);
    centroid.id = 'centroid' + '-' + i;
    allCentroids.push(centroid);
  }
  return allCentroids;
}

//same for const.
let points = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
  colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

initializeCentroids(3);

console.log(points);
```

console:

index.js:29

(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {fill: "#2ca02c", id: "centroid-2"}

1: {}

2: {fill: "#ff7f0e", id: "centroid-1"}

3: {fill: "#1f77b4", id: "centroid-0"}

4: {}

length: 5

**proto**: Array(0)

How do I remove the dependency between the variable consisting out of the object that is assigned by the array and the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

`let centroid = points[r]`

is grabbing a reference to an object in your points array

when changing `centriod` you change the object in the array as well.

Comment: What would the best way be to remove that dependency?

Comment: change it to `let centroid = {};` to make sure it's a different (new) object

Comment: But that object (centroid) has stil to be fetched out of the array of objects (points), since the empty object is only for testing purpose, is there a way to do that without having dependencies between the two?

Comment: I see, have a look at `Object.assign()` it created a copy of each property in the object into a new object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign